# Old ASUS eee cannot get past GRUB RESCUE>

Tags: boot, grub2, asus

While  attempting to upgrade an **old ASUS eee** (2 Gb, 16 GB "disk") from Ubuntu 16.04 to 18.04,  I erred and used the x64 version of 18.04, instead of the i386 Lubuntu.
Now, the system is **stuck on "grub rescue>**".
It will not boot from the "RAM".  a USB, a CDROM (via (USB), or even if I set the BIOS to "no hardidsk found".
What ***Grub Rescue*** commands can I use to at least free up the RAM and get the BIOS to see my bootable Lubuntu 18.04 i386 USB drive?

Comment: Grub exists in many parts; stage 1 is the MBR (first 512 byte sector of hdd/sdd; which consists of a pointer to later stages & the simple grub-rescue). It sounds like you've formatted or removed the later stages (1.5 & 2) of grub thus grub's pointer is wrong or of no use. There will be nothing in RAM; as grub-rescue is only loaded early (and you can't fit much code in only 512 bytes!).  You need to reboot, and your machine will follow the eeepc's bios settings as to boot order.   If you installed your usb-device on another machine; it's possibly pointing to a drive on your other pc.

Comment: For help with using grub-rescue - see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Troubleshooting

Comment: Please tell us more about your eeePC: Brand name and model, because different models behave in different ways.

Comment: Thanx.  It is an eee  901, with a VERY ARCANE BIOS menu...that I hope to use as a LAMP server, to replace my burnt Raspberry PI-II.

Answer (score 1):

**MY BAD**
This problem can be **closed (or solved)** 
Embarrassed to say that the problem was in the BIOS, not the GRUB!
In addition to the usual boot priority list menu (hard-disk, USB, CDROM, etc), there was another list item that asked whether to choose an internal disk or a USB device as a hard disk!
Of course it was set to internal disk, not the USB.
Once fixed, the system booted from, and installed my Lubuntu ISO USB easily.
In the meantime, I have become somewhat of an expert on "Grub Rescue>" commands!

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution :-) (I recognize it from an eeePC 900 owned by a friend of mine.)